# How to make an exponential progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I know aritmetic and geometric progression:

## Aritmetic progression

$$2 \xrightarrow{+2}4\xrightarrow{+2}6\xrightarrow{+2}8\xrightarrow{+2}10\xrightarrow{+2}12\xrightarrow{+2}14\xrightarrow{+2}16\xrightarrow{+2}18\xrightarrow{+2}20\xrightarrow{+2}22\xrightarrow{+2}24\xrightarrow{+2}26\xrightarrow{+2}28$$

**It's:**
$$a_{n} = a_{1}+r(n-1)$$
Or:
$$a_{n} = a_{m}+r(n-m)$$

**Where:**

- $a_{1}$ is the first term.
- $a_{n}$ is the nth term.
- $a_{m}$ is an nth term that it isn't $a_{1}$ nor $a_{n}$
- $r$ is the difference between terms.
- $n$ is the number of terms.
- $a_{m}$ is the number of terms of $a_{m}$.

**Its difference or ratio is:**
$$r=a_{n}-a_{n-1}$$

**And its sum is:**
$$S_{n} = \frac{n(a_{1}+a_{n})}{2}$$
Or if you don't want start from the first term:
$$S_{n-m} = \frac{(n-m)(a_{m}+a_{n})}{2}$$

## Geometric progression

$$2\xrightarrow{\times2}4\xrightarrow{\times2}8\xrightarrow{\times2}16\xrightarrow{\times2}32\xrightarrow{\times2}64\xrightarrow{\times2}128\xrightarrow{\times2}256\xrightarrow{\times2}512\xrightarrow{\times2}1024\xrightarrow{\times2}2048\xrightarrow{\times2}4096$$

**It's**
$$a_{n} = a_{1}\times r^{n-1}$$
Or:
$$a_{n} = a_{m}\times r^{n-m}$$

**Where:**

- $a_{1}$ is the first term.
- $a_{n}$ is the nth term.
- $a_{m}$ is an nth term that it isn't $a_{1}$ nor $a_{n}$
- $r$ is the ratio of multiplication between terms.
- $n$ is the number of terms.
- $m$ is the number of terms of $a_{m}$.

**Its difference or ratio is:**
$$r = \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$$

**And its sum is:**
$$S_{n} = {a_{1}\frac {(r^{n}-1)}{r-1}}$$
Or if you don't want start from the first term:
$$S_{n-m} = {a_{1}\frac {(r^{n-m+1}-1)}{r-1}}$$

## Now the progression I want: exponential

$$2\xrightarrow{x^2}4\xrightarrow{x^2}16\xrightarrow{x^2}256\xrightarrow{x^2}65,536\xrightarrow{x^2}4,294,967,296\xrightarrow{x^2}18,446,744,073,709,551,616$$
I have no idea of how to calculate anything related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a progression in which one number is the previous one to the power of some constant (I'm calling it x), which in your case is 2.

$$a_n=a_{n-1}^x $$

So if you take the formula for a2 and put it in the one for A3, you get:

$$a_2=a_1^x $$
$$a_3=a_2^x $$
$$a_3=(a_1^x)^x $$
$$a_3=a_1^{x^2} $$

From that, you can deduce that the power of x will increase by one for each number in the progression, so you can also deduce the general formula:

$$a_n=a_1^{x^{n-1}} $$

or

$$a_n=a_m^{x^{n-m}} $$

Another maybe useful formula is the one for x:

$$x=log_{a_{n-1}}a_n $$

Answer (score 1):

These results can be synthetized and generalized by means of the logarithm:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+r\leftrightarrow\log a_n=\log a_{n-1}+\log r\leftrightarrow\log\log a_n=\log\log a_{n-1}+\log\log r,$$ or equivalently

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+r\leftrightarrow a_n=a_{n-1}r\leftrightarrow a_n=a_{n-1}^{\log r}$$

and you can continue the nesting.

Following this logics, you get a "power progression" with power

$$r=e^{\log a_n/\log a_{n-1}}$$ and $$a_n=a_1^{\log^{n-1}r}.$$

As far as I know, there is no simple formula for the summation (but there is one for the product of the terms).

Comment: $a_n=a_1^{\log^{n-1}r}$ means $a_{n} = a_{1}^{(\log{n-1})r}$?

Comment: @EnderLook: not at all, you take the power of the logarithm.

Comment: So, you are saying $a_{n} = a_{1}^{(\log{r})^{n-1}}$?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

For $n\ge 0$,

$$a_{n+1}=a_n^{2^1}=a_{n-1}^{2^2} $$
$$=a_1^{2^n}=(2)^{(2^n)} $$

Comment: What?? What is $u$?

Comment: @EnderLook i just edited.

Comment: @EnderLook Your $S_{n-m} $ for geometric case is incorrect.

Comment: Really? I'll check that. Also, you should comment that in my question. Fixed.

Comment: You are saying $2^{(2^{2})}$ or $(2^{2})^{2}$? Because I think the second one can be also: $2^{2\times2}$

Comment: @EnderLook Now it is clear.